# What is localhost path for accessing server file in android??

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, wamp

I want to send variable from **android application** to wamp server and retrieve data from server. Please suggest me and what is path of localhost for wamp server. I am using "**localhost/TestAndroid/check.php**". The error is occurred data is not parsed.
Please suggest me with code. How to accessing data from android application(JSON+Android+HTTPClient)?.
Thanks
Nitin

Comment: Is your android phone and computer connected to the same network?

Comment: try like this- httppost = new HttpPost("http://abc.com/TestAndroid/check.php");

Comment: @varun1505 I am doing application in android & I want to fetch data from web server but for testing purpose, i want to retrieve data from local server. I am using wamp server with mysql database. I am trying to retrieve data by using JSON.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh i want to retrieve data from local server not in live web server for testing purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the below link, it may help full 
[WAMP server](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/&ei=4klSUobgNY2Jrgfp34HIDQ&usg=AFQjCNEQMf34emHq4xqVkX5D_GrHrqXNrA&bvm=bv.53537100,d.bmk&cad=rja)

Answer (score 3):

Use this localhost address in your code  '10.0.2.2/TestAndroid/check.php'

For more Help:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Make sure your PC and Phone are in the same network (Connected to the same wi-fi)
2. Open a command prompt and run `ipconfig` and get the IP adress. 99% chances are it'll be something like `192.168.X.X`
3. Use this IP instead of localhost. i.e. `192.168.X.X/TestAndroid/check.php`